# Cairo only render to specific color component

Tags: cairo

I am using Cairo and would like to render one color component at a time. For example, if I render a set of blue rectangles and then render a set of red rectangles, I want where they overlap to be purple rather than red.

Using `set_source_rgb(ctx, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` doesn't work, because it will overwrite the other channels with zeros. Using transparency doesn't work either, as it equally effects all channels. I would like a way to only render to one channel.

Is that possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CAIRO_OPERATOR_ADD` instead of `CAIRO_OPERATOR_OVER` (the default):

```
#include <cairo.h>

int main() {
    cairo_surface_t *s = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 20, 20);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(s);

    cairo_set_operator(cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_ADD);

    /* Render blue */
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, 15, 15);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    /* Render red */
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 5, 5, 15, 15);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(s, "out.png");
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(s);
    return 0;
}
```